# RecyclerView doesn't load data initially

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I made an app from which I get data from TMDB API, everything seems to work but when I start the app, it displays only hint text, after scrolling the View get's updated with the data from the API

This is how it looks before scrolling

[image: Before scrolling]

And this is how it looks after scrolling down a a bit
[image]

This is how I implemented it:

```
HomeFragment.kt

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private lateinit var popularMovies: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var popularMoviesAdapter: MoviesAdapter

    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        popularMovies = binding.popularMovies
        popularMovies.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        popularMoviesAdapter = MoviesAdapter(listOf())
        popularMovies.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        popularMovies.adapter = popularMoviesAdapter

        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        MoviesRepository.getPopularMovies(page = 1,onSuccess = ::onPopularMoviesFetched,onError =  ::onError)
    }
    private fun onPopularMoviesFetched(movies: List<Movie>) {
        popularMoviesAdapter.updateMovies(movies)
    }
    private fun onError() {
        Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.error_fetch_movies), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

MovieAdapter.kt

class MoviesAdapter(
    private var movies: List<Movie>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)

        val binding = MovieItemBinding.inflate(view)
        return MovieViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = movies.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(movies[position])
    }

    fun updateMovies(movies: List<Movie>) {
        this.movies = movies
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class MovieViewHolder(private val binding: MovieItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        private val poster: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_movie_poster)

        fun bind(movie: Movie) {

            binding.movieTitle.text =movie.title
            binding.movieReleaseDate.text = movie.releaseDate

            binding.movieOverview.text = movie.overview
            binding.movieReleaseDate.text = movie.releaseDate
            Glide.with(itemView)
                .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.posterPath}")
                .transform(CenterCrop())
                .into(poster)
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using `homeViewModel`?

Comment: That's really weird, it all looks fine to me - if it's displaying the poster, then it's getting the ``Movie`` data (with the image url) in ``bind``, so it should be setting all the other data on the ``ViewHolder`` as well. Personally I'd set a breakpoint in ``bind`` and see what's happening with your data, but since the placeholder stuff isn't being replaced *at all*, I can't really see how that code would behave like that

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine being new to Kotlin, I left that file empty, only with the generated code inside it

Answer (score 1):

make adapter initialization on **onViewCreated** instead of **onCreateView**

Comment: still the same behaviour